# HTML entity received through POST isn't comparable to entity created in the same page

Tags: php, html, entity

`$_POST["poundSymbol"] == "&pound;"` comes out as false.

Why is this and how can I bypass it?

Comment: What do you get when you do `var_dump($_POST["poundSymbol"]);`? something like `£`, `Â£` or rather `&pound;`?

Comment: `string(2) "£"`

Comment: [this](https://3v4l.org/mok8v) might help

Comment: `html_entity_decode` works. With plus symbols, it only works when you use the hex code and not the entity code, but regardless, the problem's solved. Thanks.

Comment: Note that in OP's case, `html_entity_decode` is not really necessary, it could be done simply with `$_POST["poundSymbol"] == "£"`. I haven't chosen this in my answer though so that it is more stable with different encodings.

Comment: Also, as I added in my answer, beware of loose equality `==`, see [this example](https://3v4l.org/IYR2T)

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest way to do this would be to use `htmlentities()` with an alternative. This way it would work either with `£` or `&pound;` (if you don't need support for `&pound;`, keep only the second alternative). I personnally would use strict comparison `===` for this kind of tests:

```
if($_POST["poundSymbol"] === "&pound;" || htmlentities($_POST["poundSymbol"]) === "&pound;"){
    //...
}
```